# Node.JS + Express + Socket.IO - websocket connection invalid info

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I recently found a script on [GitHub](https://github.com/rogchap/SampleProjects/tree/master/NodeChat) which allows you to run a real-time Node.JS chat application, using Express and Socket.IO dependencies. I have uploaded it to my newly acquired DigitalOcean VPS, running Ubuntu 12.04.

It *works*, but is very slow to start with, i.e. it takes ~10 seconds to load, and when I run `node app.js` command via SSH, I get this debug info in my terminal - http://pastebin.com/r48xHN3m - the app starts up with socket.IO, BUT, on line 8 you can see that there's a clear socket.IO warning, stating that the websocket connection is invalid. And then it goes on to do some XHR polling after the timeout, and in the end of the debug info (line 38), you can see that a new user has joined the group, so it *does* work.

I've read a lot on the web about this, but I still can't solve the error. I tried using SSL (port 443), updating and upgrading all the dependencies, but those minor tweaks just don't do it...

P.S. My experimental site with the node app installed, but with socket.IO errors (running on port 3000) - [chat.notepad.li](http://chat.notepad.li)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here? Unless you want us to fix a random project on Github that is clearly not meant for production...

Comment: The problem is - I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting socket errors.

Comment: Wait, I think I know the source of my errors! I have an old version of nginx!

Comment: Here, this article (hopefully) will solve my problem - http://nolanlawson.com/2013/05/31/web-sockets-with-socket-io-node-js-and-nginx-port-80-considered-harmful/

Comment: Great! If it solves it, please post it as an answer. Consider also making a pull request to the original developer with your modifications in a README

Comment: Yep, I've answered my own question =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

After scouring the web, I found out that all I needed to do was to first: **upgrade my nginx** installation, and secondly: **update my nginx configuration block** that is shown on this [website](http://nolanlawson.com/2013/05/31/web-sockets-with-socket-io-node-js-and-nginx-port-80-considered-harmful/). I then restarted the nginx service and, voila - the chat app loads up in less than a second. The website also stated that "*SSL is apparently the way to go*" -

> Incidentally, it would have worked if I had used SSL on port 443.
>   According to [WebSocketsTest’s aggregate data](http://websocketstest.com/ws/stats), port 443 is supported
>   about 89% of the time, compared to 78% for port 80.